# Junit in eclipse produces NoClassDefFoundError when using junit

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I am new to jUnit and unit testing in general, and have been trying to set up my testing environment and failing all day. This is trying to test a method in my android application.

I added a test class to the same package the java class is in. I added a method as below:

```
@Test
public void testIsExpectedNote() {
  assertTrue(Frequency.isExpectedNote(440, "A"));   
}//should return true
```

This fails with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/util/Log
    at dataLogicLayer.Frequency.isExpectedNote(Frequency.java:13)
    at dataLogicLayer.FrequencyTest.testIsExpectedNote(FrequencyTest.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.util.Log
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

Any ideas what is going wrong? I have been playing with my run configurations and in the classpath i have:

```
jre system library [jre7]
junit 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the android sdk in your classpath? search for the jar containing the class android.util.Log in your classpath

regards

Grub

Comment: Thanks, its not there, I removed it. I cant find it though, any ideas?

Comment: just put the android sdk again in your classpath :) download it and put in your project again

Comment: sorry i do have android 2.2 in my classpath, just not in the run configurations for this test class. i have the option to add jars and projects to the bootstrap entries, is this where i need it?

Comment: i added android 2.2 back in by reverting to defaults and then re-adding junit and jre system library, i now get the following error:

Comment: #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3470), pid=4588, tid=2424
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere()
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Ben\workspace...

# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to make a new project and do testing in there instead, must make it an android junit test, and make sure the run configs are correct. thanks to Grub for your help

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are mixing Android SDK and Java SDK. You should not be doing that. Android is a self sufficient library.